# Angular material : UI Screen flickers when clicked outside of Material dialog on specific Firefox version

Tags: javascript, css, angular, firefox, angular-material

I am using Angular Material dialog to fetch some date from ui and save to the database.
Overall the solution works fine.

But with some specific version of Firefox on only windows OS, a portion of ui screens flickers when we click outside of dialog anywhere.

Code for opening dialog

```
  addUser() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddComponent, {
      panelClass: 'css-style',
      data: {
       user: userDetails
      },
      autoFocus: false,
      disableClose: true
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.updateSources();
      }
    );
  }
```

Has anybody encountered any such issues.
Any help is highly appreciated.